# Block cookies from specific URLs?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible to block cookies from specific URLs programmatically e.g. JavaScript or user script , and how?

For example I have issue about YouTube search, let's say if you watch piano videos usually, then if you search "piano" simply on YouTube search ( https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=piano ), the search result will highly depend on your watching history. There is big difference between login-ed search result and incognito window search result. This is just annoying.

I found some info to block cookies from specific domains, but not for URLs ( blocks for `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=*` but allows for `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*` ). So, how can I do this using JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: some cookies can be set up in different ways so im not sure if there's a cure all.. but good question

Comment: Google has multiple ways to track you (browser fingerprinting, IP address, cookies/supercookies, etc.), so I'm not sure how effective this is. --  you might be able to find some Google settings to turn off search result personalization -- also, you might have to write some browser plugins, then it depends on which browser you're using.

Comment: I understand. I'll try that, thanks.